# strstr function does not work vs 2015

Tags: c++, string, function, visual-studio-2015

So, I have to introduce some names (it doesn't matter how) and count in how many of them I can find the substring 'ana'. I am not allowed to use char for the names, i need to use string. I wrote the code as simple as i could've thought but my strstr function does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<stdio.h>


using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string name;
    string ana;
    int ok = 0;
    int nr = 0;
    ana = "ana";
    cout << "if you want to stop entering names introduce 1 after the last name, else introduce 0.";
    while (ok == 0)
    {
        cout << "Name here: " << flush;
        getline(cin, name);
        if (strstr(name, ana) != 0)
            nr++;
        cin >> ok;
    }
    cout << "The number of names that contain 'ana' is: " << nr;
}
```

Can you please give me some help? The error is: "Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2665   'strstr': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types  T1E1    e:\uni\an ii\lf\t1e1\t1e1\e1.cpp    20  "

Comment: U cant assign string variable directly..use strcpy or memcpy to assign

i am talking about variable ana

Comment: @Grv Yes you can, this is C++ and `std::string`.

Comment: @molbdnilo ok..Thanks..

Answer (score 8):

`strstr` works with C strings, not `std::string`.

Use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead.

Instead of

```
  if (strstr(name, ana) != 0)
        nr++;
```

use

```
  if ( name.find(ana) != std::string::npos )
     nr++;
```

Comment: Another alternative is to change `std::string` to `char[]` and work with C strings

Comment: Uhm, why does this even compile? Edit: ah, of course it doesn't compile! The path made me think it was an ICE

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can include the header file `cstring` which included `strstr` function. Add the following code in your `.cpp` file.

```
#include <cstring>
```

More details at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr).